# Expand down/Collapse animation Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation, slidetoggle, expand

I have tried a few suggestions and tutorials and nothing works as supposed.
Anybody familiar with expanding layout from `0` to `100%` and collapse it back?

```
<GridLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:columnCount="3">

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="3dp"
      android:text="Hello"
      android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="3dp"
      android:text="Hello"
      android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="center"
      android:padding="3dp"
      android:text="Hello"
      android:textSize="20sp" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:text="ho-ho-ho"
      android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:text="ho-ho-ho"
      android:textAlignment="center" />

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_columnWeight="1"
      android:layout_rowWeight="1"
      android:gravity="bottom"
      android:text="ho-ho-ho"
      android:textAlignment="center" />

</GridLayout>
```

Appreciate your kind help

Comment: Are you trying to expand the entire gridlayout?

Comment: @EugeneH yes, the `gridlayout`

Comment: Does the GridLayout have a parent view?

Comment: @EugeneH It does I managed to animate it in several ways as desired but unfortunately the layout is somewhat buggy and its content disappears randomly on animation

Comment: Okay, I am going to give you a simple suggestion and see if that works. Add this to the parent view of the GridLayout:     android:animateLayoutChanges="true".  Then just call layout.setVisibility(View.GONE or View.VISIBLE) on the Gidlayout.

Comment: @EugeneH excuse me for bothering but have you ever experienced issue when expanding layout or even in general its bottom content to be cut off

Comment: I have faced that before but I believe it is fixable. Post how you are currently implementing the animation to see why it is being cut off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162548/discussion-between-eugene-h-and-jocky-doe).

Comment: try setting the  android:rowCount="" in the gridlayout

Comment: https://github.com/florent37/ExpansionPanel?utm_source=android-arsenal.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_campaign=6662

Answer (score 0):

use physics based animation

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/physics-based-animation.html

enjoy